# Which problems can cause fragment's container view id

Tags: android, android-fragments

To call new fragment currently I'm using `.add(R.id.container, fragment)` or `.replace(R.id.container, fragment)`.

and I faced with a crash

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException No view found for id

which was fixed simply replacing

`.add(R.id.container, fragment)` to `.add(((ViewGroup)getView().getParent()).getId(), fragment)`

Now I'm thinking about using `((ViewGroup)getView().getParent()).getId()` everywhere where I can in my app to avoid other crashes.

Is it good idea ? Which problems can will appear if I use this approach ? Is it safe ? Is there any better approach ?

Comment: and what is R? are you using child fragments?... didn't you mix up `your.package.R` with `android.R` ?

Answer (score 1):

**Better approach is :**

When you are going to add / replace a fragment, First check whether the

container is null or not and then perform the transaction.

```
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

            FrameLayout frame=(FrameLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.reg_frame_container);

            if(frame!=null) {
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.reg_frame_container, new SecurityQuestions()).commit();

            }
            else {
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container_menu, new SecurityQuestions()).commit();

            }
```

OR

You can use your method if it works properly but remember to check for null condition.

This Works for me.

Hope this helps :)